# Compare sheet 1 & 2 using column B1 as guide if not match copy row to sheet 3

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel which has 3 sheets. In sheet 1 and 2 i have approximately 10 columns each but has different total number of rows. I want to check if data in Sheet 2 is in Sheet 1. If it has a match then do nothing but if it has no match then copy the entire row into sheet 3.

Here's my code But I think i got it wrong

```
Sub test() 
Dim rng As Range, c As Range, cfind As Range 
On Error Resume Next 
Worksheets("sheet3").Cells.Clear 
With Worksheets("sheet1") 
Set rng = Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("a2").End(xlDown)) 
For Each c In rng 
With Worksheets("sheet2") 
Set cfind = .Columns("A:A").Cells.Find _ 
(what:=c.Value, lookat:=xlWhole) 
If cfind Is Nothing Then GoTo line1 
'c.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count,      "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 
c.Copy Worksheets("sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 
c.Offset(0, 2).Copy Worksheets("sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count,    "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 


End With 'sheet 2 
line1: 
Next c 
Application.CutCopyMode = False 
End With 'sheet 1
```

To explain it in picture refer below

**Sheet 1**
[image]

**Sheet 2**
[image]

**Sheet 3**
[image]

The Sheet 3 is my expected output. Can i obtain the output such as that.
Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one "

```
Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range, c As Range, cfind As Range

    On Error Resume Next

    Worksheets(3).Cells.Clear

    With Worksheets(1)
        Set rng = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Range("a2").End(xlDown)) 'added . (dot) in front of first range
        For Each c In rng
        With Worksheets(2)
            Set cfind = .Columns("A:A").Cells.Find _
            (what:=c.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If cfind Is Nothing Then
                'change the "10" in "Resize(1, 10)" to the number of columns you have
                c.Resize(1, 10).Copy Worksheets(3).Cells(Worksheets(3).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End If
        End With 'sheet 2
        Next c
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End With 'sheet 1

End Sub
```

### Edit for Avidan's question in comments

To check every row with every row on other sheet requires different approach. Such as :

```
Sub CopyMissingRecords()
'compare whole record in row on 1st worksheet with all records in rows on 2nd worksheet
'and if there is no such row in the 2nd worksheet, then copy the missing record to 3rd worksheet
'repeat for all records on 1st worksheet

    Dim varToCopy() As Variant
    Dim varToCompare() As Variant
    Dim intCopyRow As Integer
    Dim intCopyRowMax As Integer
    Dim intToCompareRow As Integer
    Dim intToCompareRowMax As Integer
    Dim bytColumnsInData As Byte
    Dim intMisMatchCounter As Integer
    Dim intComparingLoop As Integer
    Dim intRowMisMatch As Integer

    bytColumnsInData = 10 ' change to your situation

    'clear everything in our output columns in Worksheets(3)
    With Worksheets(3)
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, bytColumnsInData)).Clear
    End With

        With Worksheets(1)
            'last row in Worksheets(1)
            intCopyRowMax = .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

            'compare each row in Worksheets(1)
            For intCopyRow = 2 To intCopyRowMax

                'store the first row record from Worksheets(1) into memory
                ReDim varToCopy(0)
                varToCopy(0) = .Range(.Cells(intCopyRow, 1), .Cells(intCopyRow, bytColumnsInData))

                With Worksheets(2)
                    'last row in Worksheets(2)
                    intToCompareRowMax = .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

                    'loop through all rows in Worksheets(2)
                    For intToCompareRow = 2 To intToCompareRowMax

                        'store the actual row record from Worksheets(2) into memory
                        ReDim varToCompare(0)
                        varToCompare(0) = .Range(.Cells(intToCompareRow, 1), .Cells(intToCompareRow, bytColumnsInData))

                        'compare each column from the row record in Worksheets(1), with each column from the row record in Worksheets(2)
                        For intComparingLoop = 1 To bytColumnsInData
                            'if any of the cells from Worksheets(1) in compared row are different than cells from Worksheets(2) in compared row
                            'just one difference in row is enough to consider this record as missing
                            If varToCopy(0)(1, intComparingLoop) <> varToCompare(0)(1, intComparingLoop) Then
                                'store how many row MisMatches are there in data
                                intRowMisMatch = intRowMisMatch + 1
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next intComparingLoop
                    Next intToCompareRow 'next row in Worksheets(2)


                'if there are as many row mismatches as there are row records in Worksheets(2)
                If intRowMisMatch = intToCompareRowMax - 1 Then
                    With Worksheets(3)
                        'copy the entire row from Worksheets(1) to the next available row in Worksheets(3)
                        Worksheets(1).Range(Worksheets(1).Cells(intCopyRow, 1), Worksheets(1).Cells(intCopyRow, bytColumnsInData)).Copy _
                        Destination:=.Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                    End With 'Worksheets(3)
                End If

                'reset the counter
                intRowMisMatch = 0

                End With 'Worksheets(2)

            Next intCopyRow 'next row in Worksheets(1)

        End With 'Worksheets(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: What if I need column b as comparer. And if it doesnt match then copy the whole row of that cell in column b.

Comment: You want to copy and transpose the missing row into column B?

Comment: I mean...in the pictures below I want column location to be my guide to comapre. If it has no match then I will copy the entire row of that line. To be clearer, I will use column location for example is New york, new york has no match from other sheets so i will copy the entire row of New York.

Comment: If you want just the location as your guide, then change every "A" in the code I posted, with "C". That should work. However, if you will have more records (different Names and Dogs) in New York location in Sheet1, and some of these records will not be in Sheet2, this will not copy the missing records. In other words, this code only compares the location, not the records as a whole, so it is possible that logical errors will arise.

Comment: @BranislavKollár Nice :)
I have one query for you; Assume both the sheets have same `Name`s columns and the remaining columns may have different values. What change I can make here so that I can get only those Names in my sheet2 for whose remaining columns are changed(different)

Comment: @ Avidan Check the Edit, if that is what you meant.